# How to use npm link with a module written using TypeScript for development?

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, package.json, npm-link

I am building a lib using TypeScript and Webpack.

To develop this library I have created a separate test project (written using JS) and linked the library using `npm link <package-name>`.

The problem is that the link leads to the build file and I need to run `npm run build` every time I make a change.

I want to have a link to the source file and have a live reload. Is it possible? Do I need to write my test project using TS also to make it possible?

Library `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "lib/qr-code-styling.js",
  "files": [
    "lib"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  ...
}
```

Code of the library https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling/tree/v1

Code of test project https://github.com/kozakdenys/qr-code-styling-site

P.S. I also tried `"module": "src/index.ts"` in `package.json`, but it causes an error in the test project `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './core/QRCodeStyling'`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you need to write your test project in TypeScript as well. After that you need to map the package to the linked module source files in the test project `tsconfig` file.

In the `compilerOptions` entry of the `tsconfig` file add a `baseUrl` and a `paths` entry like the following the example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "linked-module-name": ["node_modules/linked-module-name/src"],
      "linked-module-name/*": ["node_modules/linked-module-name/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Read more about path mapping in the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping).

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to have your TS project automatically rebuild using `tsc --watch` and then use the compiled code in your project via `npm link ../path/to/dep`

Answer (score 1):

This can be set up on your `tsconfig.json` file, as it is a TS feature.

You can do like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
         ...
        "paths": {
            "@app/*": ["app/*"],
            "@config/*": ["app/_config/*"],
            "@environment/*": ["environments/*"],
            "@shared/*": ["app/_shared/*"],
            "@helpers/*": ["helpers/*"]
        },
        ...
```

Have in mind that the `path` where you want to refer to, it takes your `baseUrl` as the base of the `route` you are pointing to and it's **mandatory** as described on the doc.

The character '**@**' is not mandatory.

After you set it up on that way, you can easily use it like this:

```
import { Yo } from '@config/index';
```

the only thing you might notice is that the intellisense does not work in the current latest version, so I would suggest to follow an index convention for importing/exporting files.

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

you can checkout here

> https://github.com/ialex90/TypeScript-Node-Starter/commit/a4e8cc1f8f8d5176e0099e05b51f97b0ef4bebea